# Dynamic list not rendering in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a list of movie genres for a simple app.  The data is stored in the state, but when trying to render the list nothing is appearing. Here is the component:

```
import React from 'react';

class GetGenres extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {genres: []}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const genres = []
        const url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=XXXX&language=en-US"
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
            genres.push(data.genres[i].name)
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error))



        this.setState({genres: genres})
}




/*this.setState({genres: genres});*/


    render() {
        console.log(this.state.genres)
        return (
           <div className='genre-list'> 
           <h1>Genre's</h1>
            <ul>
                {this.state.genres.map((genre, i) => {
                    return <li key={i}>{genre}</li>
                })}
            </ul>

            </div> 
        )
    }
}
```

Probably a very simple fix. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Never share your API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous call on `componentDidMount`, which means that the code inside promise resolve handlers will be executed later that your current `this.setState` -call. This is easy to fix just by setting the set state inside of the promise handler:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const genres = [];

  const url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=a2986eaf427243d1e89aafc1fc124089&language=en-US"

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        genres.push(data.genres[i].name)
      }
      // Here you will have something to show...
      this.setState({genres: genres})
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You `setState` outside of your `then`, which executes long before your `.then` callback happens. Execute it inside

```
.then(data => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        genres.push(data.genres[i].name)
    }
    this.setState({genres: genres})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the this.setState() part inside the promise that returns the data.

Nothing is rendering because after the fetch request is triggered your code will move on and call setstate with an empty array.

Remove the for loop and just call

```
this.setState({ genres: data.genres })
```